# Error while decrypting the password for BPEL Profile embeded_bps

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I configured new CA certificates for WSO2 Identity server.
I have used GREP and replaces wso2carbon.jks and replaced with my new .jks.

I think I wrongly replaced some places which I shouldn't have.
Can somebody tell me which place might have caused below exception?
Or is it because of some other problem?

```
org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl.WorkflowImplException: Error while decrypting the password for BPEL Profile embeded_bps
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl.dao.BPSProfileDAO.getBPSProfile(BPSProfileDAO.java:158)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl.WorkflowImplServiceImpl.getBPSProfile(WorkflowImplServiceImpl.j

  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.core.util.CryptoException: errorDuringDecryption
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.CryptoUtil.decrypt(CryptoUtil.java:186)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.CryptoUtil.base64DecodeAndDecrypt(CryptoUtil.java:200)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl.dao.BPSProfileDAO.decryptPassword(BPSProfileDAO.java:264)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl.dao.BPSProfileDAO.getBPSProfile(BPSProfileDAO.java:156)
        ... 108 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: unknown key type passed to RSA
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineInit(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineInit(Unknown Source)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1065)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1009)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.CryptoUtil.decrypt(CryptoUtil.java:181)
```

... 111 more

Comment: Do you have BPS AnalyticsServerProfile enabled?

Comment: I have not done anything specially to enable it..
I am using a prepackaged version...I just installed my new certificates

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same thing after updating ssl cert with alias wso2carbon. The wso2 docs explicitly say this is fine but when you change it everything stops working :(

Comment: Please make sure the Alias is fine..Can you check your key alias?

Comment: Make sure you are using the same alias which you have used while using keytool...
you might have used a different alias other than wso2carbon... in that case ,you have to update the config files with new alias

Answer (score 1):

You need to find this table: WF_BPS_PROFILE with this colums: 
HOST_URL_MANAGER, HOST_URL_WORKER, USERNAME,PASSWORD

I think that the value in PASSWORD was encripted with the previous key in wso2cabon.jks so you need to replace that value with a new one.

For more information you can find the class BPSProfileDAO.java

And the method definition:

```
    /**
     * Retrieve details of a BPS profile
     *
     * @param profileName     Name of profile to retrieve
     * @param tenantId        Id of tenant domain
     * @param isWithPasswords Whether password to be retrieved or not
     * @return
     * @throws WorkflowImplException
     */
    public BPSProfile getBPSProfile(String profileName, int tenantId, boolean isWithPasswords) throws
                                                                                               WorkflowImplException
{

        BPSProfile bpsProfileDTO = null;
        Connection connection = IdentityDatabaseUtil.getDBConnection();
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = null;
        ResultSet rs;
        String query = SQLConstants.GET_BPS_PROFILE_FOR_TENANT_QUERY;

        try {
            prepStmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            prepStmt.setString(1, profileName);
            prepStmt.setInt(2, tenantId);
            rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                String managerHostName = rs.getString(SQLConstants.HOST_URL_MANAGER_COLUMN);
                String workerHostName = rs.getString(SQLConstants.HOST_URL_WORKER_COLUMN);
                String user = rs.getString(SQLConstants.USERNAME_COLUMN);
                bpsProfileDTO = new BPSProfile();
                bpsProfileDTO.setProfileName(profileName);
                bpsProfileDTO.setManagerHostURL(managerHostName);
                bpsProfileDTO.setWorkerHostURL(workerHostName);
                bpsProfileDTO.setUsername(user);

                if (isWithPasswords) {
                    String password = rs.getString(SQLConstants.PASSWORD_COLUMN);
                    try {
                        bpsProfileDTO.setPassword(decryptPassword(password));
                    } catch (CryptoException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        throw new WorkflowImplException("Error while decrypting the password for BPEL Profile "
                                + profileName, e);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new WorkflowImplException("Error when executing the sql.", e);
        } finally {
            IdentityDatabaseUtil.closeAllConnections(connection, null, prepStmt);
        }
        return bpsProfileDTO;
    }
```

The query:

```
public static final String GET_BPS_PROFILE_FOR_TENANT_QUERY = "SELECT HOST_URL_MANAGER, HOST_URL_WORKER, " +
        "USERNAME,PASSWORD FROM WF_BPS_PROFILE WHERE PROFILE_NAME = ? AND " +
        "TENANT_ID = ? ";
```

Some util methods:

```
private String encryptPassword(char[] passwordValue) throws CryptoException {

    CryptoUtil cryptoUtil = CryptoUtil.getDefaultCryptoUtil();
    return cryptoUtil.encryptAndBase64Encode(toBytes(passwordValue));
}



private char[] decryptPassword(String passwordValue) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, CryptoException {

    CryptoUtil cryptoUtil = CryptoUtil.getDefaultCryptoUtil();
    byte[] decryptedPasswordBytes = cryptoUtil.base64DecodeAndDecrypt(passwordValue);
    return (new String(decryptedPasswordBytes, WFImplConstant.DEFAULT_CHARSET)).toCharArray();

}

/**
 * Convert a char array into a byte array
 *
 * @param chars
 * @return
 */
private byte[] toBytes(char[] chars) {
    CharBuffer charBuffer = CharBuffer.wrap(chars);
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = Charset.forName(WFImplConstant.DEFAULT_CHARSET).encode(charBuffer);
    byte[] bytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(byteBuffer.array(),
            byteBuffer.position(), byteBuffer.limit());
    Arrays.fill(charBuffer.array(), '\u0000');
    Arrays.fill(byteBuffer.array(), (byte) 0);
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Yup. Try clearing the table and restart this error should go away. There is an embedded bps that ships with wso2 is. On the first startup we encrypt the default password which is an empty string and put it in the database.

Answer (score 1):

In general, such errors can occur when the server already have saved certain data (eg. passwords) encrypted with the public key in the default keystore. So when you change the keystore, it can no longer decrypt those data. So ideally, you should change keystores as the first thing in your production deployment.

In your case, you can try changing `<Credential>` under `<ServerProfile>` accordingly (maybe set `securePassword="false"` for now).

Read [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS350/Business+Process+Monitoring+with+DAS+3.0.0) and [this](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/BPS-1126) for details.

Comment: Which file has this property?
I cant find this property at all